# __debugbreak() make windbg BUSY(Debuggee is running...)

Tags: debugging, windbg

I want to debug my code, so I add `__debugbreak();` at the line that I want to break, then I build and run my program, then the windbg is invoked as expected(I had set up windbg properly in regedit, so that the `__debugbreak()` will make windbg attach my program). But, windbg can't stop the program at the line that I add `__debugbreak();` but **BUSY(Debuggee is running...)** like below:
[image]
What's the problem? How can I deal with it?

The last output in the command window is:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.22473.1005 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

*** wait with pending attach

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
OK                                             G:\nemu-vbox6\out\win.amd64\release\stage\debug\bin
Symbol search path is: srv*;G:\nemu-vbox6\out\win.amd64\release\stage\debug\bin
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00007ff7`f28c0000 00007ff7`f2e59000   C:\Program Files\Muvm6Vbox\Hypervisor\Muvm6SVC.exe
ModLoad: 00007ffb`98850000 00007ffb`98a45000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`97f40000 00007ffb`97ffe000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ffb`96260000 00007ffb`96528000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`91840000 00007ffb`918d0000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\apphelp.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`97d80000 00007ffb`97d88000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ffb`982b0000 00007ffb`98451000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`96230000 00007ffb`96252000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`98280000 00007ffb`982ab000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`95f70000 00007ffb`9607b000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`96080000 00007ffb`9611d000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`95530000 00007ffb`9557b000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\POWRPROF.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`96580000 00007ffb`96680000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`63490000 00000000`63528000   C:\Program Files\Muvm6Vbox\Hypervisor\MSVCP100.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`63530000 00000000`63602000   C:\Program Files\Muvm6Vbox\Hypervisor\MSVCR100.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`98000000 00007ffb`980ac000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`978c0000 00007ffb`979ea000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`98650000 00007ffb`986ee000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`96c60000 00007ffb`96cfb000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`97180000 00007ffb`978bf000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`95400000 00007ffb`954cb000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`4ba10000 00007ffb`4ba77000   C:\Program Files\Muvm6Vbox\Hypervisor\Muvm6DDU.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`96d00000 00007ffb`97172000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\SETUPAPI.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`96530000 00007ffb`9657e000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`4b380000 00007ffb`4ba0a000   C:\Program Files\Muvm6Vbox\Hypervisor\Muvm6RT.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`96870000 00007ffb`96897000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcrypt.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`97ed0000 00007ffb`97f3b000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`98140000 00007ffb`9826a000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`968a0000 00007ffb`96bf5000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`97da0000 00007ffb`97e6d000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`8e9a0000 00007ffb`8e9aa000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`96680000 00007ffb`967d6000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPT32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`953c0000 00007ffb`953fb000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ffb`953a0000 00007ffb`953b2000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\UMPDC.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`98270000 00007ffb`98278000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\NSI.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`97cd0000 00007ffb`97d00000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ffb`979f0000 00007ffb`97a9d000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`94060000 00007ffb`947f0000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\windows.storage.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`959c0000 00007ffb`959ee000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Wldp.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`96c00000 00007ffb`96c55000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\shlwapi.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`95eb0000 00007ffb`95ecf000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`94810000 00007ffb`94822000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`967e0000 00007ffb`96863000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`985a0000 00007ffb`98649000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\clbcatq.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`841d0000 00007ffb`841e9000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\amsi.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`95e30000 00007ffb`95e5e000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`84180000 00007ffb`841c4000   C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpOav.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`83fa0000 00007ffb`83fd5000   C:\Program Files\McAfee\McAfee\Endpoint Security\Threat Prevention\MfeAmsiProvider.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`961d0000 00007ffb`96230000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\WINTRUST.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`95930000 00007ffb`9593c000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ffb`95b50000 00007ffb`95b62000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSASN1.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`83c60000 00007ffb`83c7c000   C:\Program Files\McAfee\McAfee\Endpoint Security\Threat Prevention\blframeworku.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`83760000 00007ffb`837a2000   C:\Program Files\McAfee\McAfee\Endpoint Security\Threat Prevention\LogLib.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`94b50000 00007ffb`94b83000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`95910000 00007ffb`95928000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`95030000 00007ffb`95064000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`97d00000 00007ffb`97d1d000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\imagehlp.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`94830000 00007ffb`94853000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\gpapi.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`8e060000 00007ffb`8e091000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cryptnet.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`66f30000 00000000`66f53000   C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\SystemCore\mfehida.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`66ef0000 00000000`66f2a000   C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\SystemCore\mfemmsa.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`92ab0000 00007ffb`92b4e000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`986f0000 00007ffb`98805000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`95d10000 00007ffb`95d44000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`90a20000 00007ffb`90a37000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ffb`90930000 00007ffb`9094d000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ffb`7b7d0000 00007ffb`7b848000   C:\Windows\System32\NetSetupShim.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`8c730000 00007ffb`8c756000   C:\Windows\System32\NetSetupApi.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`88530000 00007ffb`88544000   C:\Windows\System32\DEVRTL.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`91680000 00007ffb`9168b000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINNSI.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ffb`4b290000 00007ffb`4b37d000   C:\Program Files\Muvm6Vbox\Hypervisor\Muvm6ProxyStub.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`7a220000 00007ffb`7a22a000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msiltcfg.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`79e90000 00007ffb`7a1bd000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msi.dll
onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\channelb.cxx(7124)\combase.dll!00007FFB96999093: (caller: 00007FFB968C8A69) ReturnHr(1) tid(3f9c) 80010105 服务器出现意外情况。
(3c18.3f9c): Unknown exception - code 80010105 (first chance)
```

Comment: Could you post the last output in the command window as text, please? 80010105 is an automation error.

Comment: @ThomasWeller `(3c18.3f9c): Unknown exception - code 80010105 (first chance)`, and I have edited my post, you can check it out.

Comment: Thanks for providing the info. And you used [AeDebug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/configuring-automatic-debugging) to make WinDbg run when an application crashes. Is that right?

Comment: @ThomasWeller, yes, that's right.

Comment: these days there are lots of symbol downloading problems shut off internet or use !sym noisy to see if it is spinning busy in downloading aborting ,redownloading cycles you can also confirm if there are several *.error files in cache directory f:\symbols>dir /b /s *.error
f:\symbols\combase.pdb\6BEF27DA5358761C5348429AE04DDB4D1\download0C18CEB699054219932797399B0428AA.error  i see a combase in your screen shot

Comment: @blabb, yes, I found several *.error files in pdb directory, so, how to deal with it?

Comment: you cant as far as i know  ... it has  become a chronic problem for anyone trying to download symbols on a home network or mobile networks some times it downloads upto 15 20 partial aborted downloads of several sizes ranging from 2kd to 4mb before some how downloading and decompressing a full pdb